# MadelineProto Telegram API глобальный поиск по сообщениям

Tags: api, telegram, madelineproto

Всем привет.

Мне нужно сделать поиск по всем сообщение открытых чатов по ключевому слову(например nike), использовав метод https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/API_docs/methods/messages_search.html , удалось получить результаты только если указывать ник конкретного канала в параметре "peer", в документации https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.search указываеться что если передавать в конткукторе inputPeerEmpty то поиск должен проходить глобально, но если я указую етот конструтор то поиск происходит только по привязаному профилю юзера (((

Подскажите пожалуйста как возможно решить эту проблему? Может я чего то не  учел? Или что то делаю не так как нужно? Или же библиотека не поддержывает глобального поиска по месседжам? Заранее благодарен за любую полезную информацыю =)

Вот данные которые я передаю в параметрах:

```
$messages_Messages = $MadelineProto->messages->search([
    'peer' => ['_' => 'inputPeerEmpty'],
    'q' => 'Web',
    'min_date' => 1514764800,
    'max_date' => 1563667200,
    'offset_id' => 0,
    'add_offset' => 0,
    'limit' => 100,
    'max_id' => 0,
    'min_id' => 0,
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Для глобального поиска используйте [messages.searchGlobal](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/API_docs/methods/messages.searchGlobal.html), пример из документации:

```
if (!file_exists('madeline.php')) {
    copy('https://phar.madelineproto.xyz/madeline.php', 'madeline.php');
}
include 'madeline.php';

$MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API('session.madeline');
$MadelineProto->start();

$messages.Messages = $MadelineProto->messages->searchGlobal(
    ['folder_id' => int, 'q' => 'string', 'offset_rate' => int, 
     'offset_peer' => InputPeer, 'offset_id' => int, 'limit' => int, ]);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, в следующий раз приводите вместе с ссылкой её краткое содержание. Обычно, сообщения как ваше в первой редакции, просто удаляются.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не знал. Спасибо за информацию, впредь буду придерживаться этого правила.